# Getting a while loop to continue with a if statement

Tags: java

I'm working with a while loop and an if statement.

I want the loop to continue if the else statement is being run. In my understanding the "continue;" should restart the loop, but it doesn't.

I found one workaround to fix this though, it's to set "cho = 1;". But is this really necessary? Are there any more logic ways to solve this problem?

Thanks!

```
    while (sum < 21 && cho == 1 && sum != 21) {
        System.out.println("Do you want to (1)hit or (2) stay?");
        cho = scan.nextInt();

        if (cho == 1) {

            getCard(index++);

            if (sum > 21) {
                System.out.println("You busted! Dealer wins.");
                return;
            }
        } else if (cho == 2) {
            System.out.println("Your value is " + sum);
            sum = playerTotal;
        }
        else{
            cho = 1;
            System.err.println("The input value given is not a valid integer");
            continue; //Does not restart the loop.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Define "does not work".  When you step through this in a debugger, what *does* it do?  The `continue` operation does exactly what you describe, and it seems more likely that you've made a logical error than that the `continue` keyword "does not work".

Comment: `continue` WILL repeat the loop, but if your condition has changed, then your loop will end.

Comment: Okay I see, the condition changes when the input isn't equal to 1 or 2. I didn't understand that the conditions still had to be true to make the continue to work, I thought it did an override. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A `continue` jumps back to the condition of the loop which is then evaluated again. If the condition evaluates to `false`, the loop will obviously not be run again.

So if you want your loop to continue actually looping, you have to make sure that the condition is `true`.

This means: You have to set `cho = 1` and make sure `sum < 21`

Also note that the `sum != 21` in your condition is not needed, since `sum < 21` already eliminates that possibility.

Comment: Thanks, this clarifies a lot and did indeed solve the problem! I'm quite new to programming so excuse me for my pseudoscience.